Get property types in Vue Composition API
When importing a component is it possible to get its properties type?
For example:
import MyComponent from '.my-component.vue';

const props: ComponentProps<MyComponent> = {

};

Any idea how to compose ComponentProps?

In this case do you want to get the type of props generated from ComponentProps<MyComponent>?

@EstusFlask thanks, exactly what i was looking for

I recommend to define the prop options inside a script block and get their type using ExtractPropTypes utility and expose this type :
<script lang="ts">
import { ExtractPropTypes } from 'vue'

export const propsOptions = {
  foo: String,
  bar: Boolean,
  baz: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  qux: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  }
} as const


export type CompProps = ExtractPropTypes<typeof propsOptions>

</script>
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps(propsOptions)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

This makes the component props type reusable and have one source, without extracting them every time the component is used in parent. They also can serve as a parameter type in a composable.

You can simply export the props type from the component.
Icon.vue component
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface Props {
  name: string;
}

defineProps<Props>();
</script>

<template>
  <svg>
    <use :href="'#icon-' + name" />
  </svg>
</template>

Home.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import AppIcon, { type Props } from '@/components/AppIcon.vue';

const icon: Props = {
  name: 'heart',
};
</script>

<template>
  <AppIcon v-bind="icon"></AppIcon>
</template>


